# rails link_to video not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I had this line of code in my html.erb file in the static folder:

```
<a href="<%= video['link'] %>" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><%= video['caption'] %></a>
```

I changed it to:

```
<%= link_to video['link'], video['caption'], role: 'tab', data: { toggle: 'tab' } %>
```

Now my video is not loading and the caption is showing up as the URL of the video. Can anybody tell me what's going on here.

Thanks.

Comment: The first argument to link_to is the displayed text, ie the content of the tag, not the href.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

You change it to:

```
<%= link_to video['caption'], video['link'], role: 'tab', data: { toggle: 'tab' } %>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this....

```
<%= link_to video['caption'], video['link'], role: 'tab', data: { toggle: 'tab' } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

link_to helper take display text as first parameter and url as second parameter. So

```
<%= link_to video['caption'], video['link'], role: 'tab', data: { toggle: 'tab' } %>
```

Or if you need formatted html instead of plain text, try something like

```
<%= link_to video['link'], role: 'tab', data: { toggle: 'tab' } do %>
   <b><%= video[:caption] %></b>
<% end %>
```

For more details, please visit apidock

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to